# Image will shake when pinching it in ScrollView and ImageView

Tags: ios, imageview, scrollview, zooming, pinch

I followed the Standford CS193P course and wrote a program which can zoom a picture in an ImageView embedded in a ScrollView. When I'm pinching, it works, the picture will "shake" continually. I recorded a video of this: [dropbox video link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3357135/ScrollViewProblem.mov)

My code is pretty simple:

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return self.imageView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=self.imageView.frame.size;
    self.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height);
}
```

And I set `max` and `min` for zooming in storyboard to 5 and 0.2.

Why would this shaking happen?